# $this.parent().find .removeClass doesnot remove class

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some issue with the following

if I add an extra column     in the loop the ccs class is not removed via the jquery script.  If i remove the   it works..

```
<?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
    <td>
       <a class="option-detail"> <img src="image"></a>
    </td>
<?php } ?>
```

What Am i doing wrong ?

Part of the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("a.option, a.option-detail").click(function(event){
         $this = $(this);
         $this.parent().find('a.option, a.option-detail').removeClass('option-active');
        $this.addClass('option-active');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `parent` isn't enough to get you to the top level within which the nodes you need to alter exist.

I.E. that you are just moving up to the `tr` that contains the `td`, and not the `table`?

Without a bit more code (more of the HTML generation) it's hard to be sure.

My best guess is that you actually need to find the `closest` table instead of the `parent`.

E.g.

```
$this.closest( 'table' ).find('a.option, a.option-detail').removeClass( 'option-active' );
```

[This fiddle give you an example of what I'm suggesting...](http://jsfiddle.net/kfyhLccx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you taking a click event on "a.option" and then going out to the parent and finding the anchor again before you remove and add the class? Wouldn't it be easier to do the following:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.option, a.option-detail', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $('.option-active').removeClass('option-active');
    $this.addClass('option-active');
}
```

Comment: corrected the html .. was a type when writing the question :(

Comment: @cappy39 no worries, updated the answer, hope that works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  I will have serval links with images in the loop and when selecting the other image the css styling should be removed from the active one (previous) and set to the one which i had clicked..  With toggleClass removes the styling when i click it again and that is not ecaxtly what i want

Comment: Couldn't you just find the one that has the "option-active" - remove it and then set it to the current one instead of going through the parent and find?

Comment: That works, assuming that there's only one table on screen that can have active options.  If there are two then clicking on one will wipe out the active option class on both tables.

Comment: @RobBaillie - this is true!

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a class="option-detail"><img src="image"></a>` (remove `a.` before)

because with this:

`<a class="a.option-detail" <img src="image"></a>` your class name will be `.a.option-detail`

and fix your htm with closing `>`

Comment: corrected this in my question..   to  <a class="option-detail" <img src="image"></a>  made a type while copying the code